# In git, how can I efficiently delete all refs matching a pattern?

Tags: git

I have over time archived a bunch of build tags in `refs/builds/archived/*` and I now want to delete them to recover some space and reduce total object count (over 50k annotated git tags are stored there).

It would appear that the only way to do this is like so:

```
git show-ref\
 | awk '/refs\/builds\/archived\/[^\/]*$/ { print "git update-ref -d "$2}'\
 | sh
```

This is extremely slow. Also, doing this appears to slow down any git fetches done from the repo until I get to run `git gc` on it.

Comment: Start with `git for-each-ref` rather than `git show-ref`; that will get you the set of refs in a single command. Unfortunately bulk delete is still going to be slow: `git update-ref -d` only works on one at a time. You can use either xargs (`-n 1`) or, as in your own code here, sh, to invoke `git update-ref`.

Comment: `git update-ref` takes a `--stdin` flag that lets you pass multiple instructions to it.

Comment: @KevinBallard: oh, nice, I never considered the `--stdin` method. That should help a lot on some systems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to say something like

```
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/builds/archived | git update-ref --stdin
```

This should do the whole thing in one bulk operation. Note that I haven't actually tried this myself.

Comment: I'll try this over the weekend and get back... I like the "stay within git" aspect of this solution.